# Pandas: Extract/Show indexes of rows with equal values in two columns and different value in a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have a `df` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {"name":  ["nameA", "nameB", "nameC", "nameD", "nameA", "nameB", "nameC", "nameD", "nameE", "nameA", "nameC", "nameD"],
        "id": [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 100, 300, 400],
        "value": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v1", "v2", "v105", "v107", "v5", "v1", "v3615", "v4"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image: original DF]

I want to group the rows if they are duplicated values in `name` and `id` and different values in the `value` column. The idea is that if `name` and `id` are the same, they must have same `value` which is not always true and **I want to extract the offending indexes**. For example, **I want to have an output like this:**

```
(2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11)
```

where the name and ID are the same but the value on one of the duplicated rows is different, like `("v4", "v107", "v4")`.

I can group the values with `duplicated` but I am getting a list of all duplicated values

```
df[df.duplicated(["name", "id"])]
```

This results in

[image: duplicated values]

The values under index 4 and 9 are the same so I don't care about this one.

I guess this is really simple but I am just stuck at this for at least an hour and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) + [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) to extract the lists of indexes where the group has unique values >= 2, as follows:

```
idx_lst_all = df.groupby(['name', 'id'])['value'].agg(lambda x : x.index[x.nunique() >=2]).values

# convert non-empty lists to tuples
idx_lst_selected = [tuple(x[0]) for x in idx_lst_all if x.size > 0]
```

**Result:**

```
print(idx_lst_selected)

[(2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11)]
```

### Edit

If your Pandas version does not support the codes above, you can use:

```
idx_lst_all = df.groupby(['name', 'id'])['value'].agg(lambda x : x.index[x.nunique() >=2].tolist()).to_numpy()

# convert non-empty lists to tuples
idx_lst_selected = [tuple(x[0]) for x in idx_lst_all if x != []]
```

Same result.

Comment: I am getting an error: "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar" when trying to execute the aggregation.

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov  What Pandas version you use?   Edited my solution to add a version  changed slightly for different Pandas versions.  Try and let me know the result.  Thanks!

Comment: I am using pandas 1.1.5

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov  The first version works for Pandas version 1.3.  Great that the revised version works for you.  It's good my answer now includes versions works for more various Pandas versions now.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` and `filter`

```
out = df.groupby(["name", "id"]).filter(lambda x : x['value'].nunique() == len(x))
```

Comment: Actually, this returns a dataframe consisting of the offending "nameC" and "300" and then "nameE" and 500 which a unique combo.